# change color of outer div by clicking on inner div (only css and html)

Tags: html, css

I have a nested div, one inside another, like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

something like this:

[image]

and I want to change the color of outer div by clicking on inner div, is that possible at all?

**

> **only by html and css, no javascript!**

**

Comment: What have you tried? Are you looking for a JavaScript solution or just CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Of course it's possible.
You can define addEventListener for the inner DOM, and set the color to `style.background` inside click function.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("outer")[0].style.background = 'yellow';
});
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    Outer
    <div class="inner">
        Inner
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parentElement` property to modify `.outer` style like this:

```js
    document.querySelectorAll('.inner')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.parentElement.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: blue;');
    });
```

```css
.outer {background-color: pink; height: 400px;}
.inner {background-color: yellow; width: 50%; height: 50%; margin: auto;}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <h1>Outer</h1>
    <div class="inner">
        <h2>Inner</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Read more about `parentElement` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement)